# Android : How to create Cursor object to get item id in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

How to create cursor object to get item id from database?

Here is my method of DBHelper, see the Cursor method

```
public int getItemIdByPosition(int position) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    return Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be correct.
Maybe the position passed through method is not correct, maybe is more efficient is you use, instead of pass a position on your method pass the ID:

```
"select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where id = " = id
```

Also you can use:
`cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)` instead of `cursor.getString(0)`

Your code seems to be right, I just would check the below things that I mentioned.

Comment: How can I pass the `id` value here? I got you want me to pass position but that value position is position of item in listView, which is not same as database row id. And that's where I'm stuck. Please check my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393156/deleting-item-from-listview-deletes-some-another-item-from-sqlite-database

Comment: `setOnItemClickListener`, you can use:
`myListView.getItemAtPosition(position);`

With that I think you will have the ID in your object from your listview, right?

Comment: Apurva, Did you get any success?

Comment: Yes, I got solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393156/deleting-item-from-listview-deletes-some-another-item-from-sqlite-database/28398016#28398016

Comment: Nice, select any response on this thread to be the Answer, then your question you have an Answer ;)

Comment: This is correct answer which i want . Thanks-you so much @JonasOliveira

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code hope you can get a help from this

```
   private void displayListView(String getter){
    //get the customer data from the db and feed them to cursor and load the   data to lest 
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchallcustomercompany(getter);

    String[] columns = new String[] {
            //get the needed columns of the db and feed them in to string array

        DBCreater.Key_customer_Shop
    };

    int[] to = new int[]{
            //get the textboxs in xml layout,which going to display the values in to integer array  
            R.id.tv_demo_search_text_Isuru
    };
    //address the xml list view to java
    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_searchcustomer_cuzlist_Isuru);
    // feed the context,displaying layout,data of db, data source of the data and distination of the data
    if(cursor.getCount()==0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " No matching data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
     dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.demo_search, cursor, columns, to,0);
     //load the data to list view
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    //what happen on when user click on the item of the list view

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor cursor =(Cursor)listView.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            //get the value of the customer name from the clicked listitem
            String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("customer_shop"));


        }

    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + POSITION + " = " + position;

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    int userId;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        userId = cursor.getInt(0);  
    }

    cursor.close();
    return userId;
```

Comment: I got you want me to pass position but that value position is position of item in listView, which is not same as database row id. And that's where I'm stuck. Please check my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393156/deleting-item-from-listview-deletes-some-another-item-from-sqlite-database

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public int getItemIdByPosition(int position) {

    int itemID = 0;
    Cursor localCursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME,
            null);
    int i = localCursor.getColumnIndex("ID");
    if (localCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {

            itemID = Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(i));
        } while (localCursor.moveToPosition(position));
    }
    localCursor.close();
    return itemID;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this code but I'm sure this code tries to match listview item position with database row id. In my case it is not always same, e.g. for a same item listview item position could be 3 and database row id larger than that number