# Display different information in activity when listview is clicked

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-listview, row

I want listview to open a new activity and display certain information when clicked in certain row of listview.
So far i am only able to display same information when clicked on every row . i dont know how to set these information for particular row so that for example when i click on row 1 this address is shown and when i click on row 2 another address shown and .....my code are as follows

First activity

```
 // storing string resources into Array
 String []Buildings_halls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.halls);
    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.hallstudent, R.id.listhall, Buildings_halls));

 }

 protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
     super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);     

Intent intent = new Intent(StudentHall.this, StudentHallSelect.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("position", position);
// Or / And
intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id));
intent.putExtra("description",getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hallsdescription));
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);

        }               

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

second activity

```
        Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();

                if (intent !=null){
        int position = intent.getInt("position", 0);     

        String[] halldetails = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hallsdescription);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.select_details);
        txt.setText(halldetails[1]);

        txt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.details_select);
        txt2.setText(halldetails[0]); 

        // Here we turn your string.xml in an array
        String[] myKeys = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.halls);

        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selecthalllist);
        myTextView.setText(myKeys[position]);


    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

i.e info for row 1 that i want to display

```
<string-array name="descriptions">
           <item>Address:</item>
                <item>  Contact: </item>
                      <item>OpeningHours:</item>
               </string-array>
```

i.e info for row 1 that i want to display

```
  <string-array name="hallsdescription">
           <item >Address:, Telephone No:,Opening Times:</item>
           <item >Address:Catherine Street, Telephone No:657263912739,Opening Times:23:00</item>
```

thanks

Comment: check this answer for same problem

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393156/deleting-item-from-listview-deletes-some-another-item-from-sqlite-database/28398016#28398016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
 super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);     

    Intent intent = new Intent(StudentHall.this, StudentHallSelect.class);
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        intent.putExtra("description",getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hallsdescription)[0]);
        break;
    case 1:
        intent.putExtra("description",getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hallsdescription)[1]);
        break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In your second activity,

```
txt.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("description"));
```